# Reduce the vertical spacing in the question title on the timeline page

Tags: feature-request, timeline, android, whitespace, mobile-chrome

There is too much vertical spacing in the question title on the timeline page when viewed on Chrome with Android. I'd suggest reducing it.

Example from https://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/604021/timeline viewed with Chrome with Android 13 and a Samsung Galaxy S23.

[image: f]